# Событие onscroll, как узнать в какую сторону крутят колесо?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Вот, собственно, сабж!

```
onscroll = function () {
    alert("scrolling");
}
```

А как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке вверх вызывалась одна функция,
а при прокрутке вниз - другая?

Comment: Еще здесь [http://webew.ru/articles/349.webew](http://webew.ru/articles/349.webew) кроссбраузерный способ.

Comment: да, тоже самое=)

Comment: Ну зато это первая ссылка гугля :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[JavaScript F.A.Q: Часть 2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124327/)** раздел 10. "Как узнать в какую сторону юзер крутит колесо мыши?"

Comment: Сделал ответом)

Comment: Отличный ответ!спасибо!

Comment: Теперь всё понятно!!! Спасибо, друзья!!